# Global Substitution

Tags: perl, global, substitution

Hi I am using the below code to replace date formats but I am unable to figure out how to globally change all dates. Currently, the script finds and replaces the dates correctly, but it only does it for the first date found within a line but skips the rest of that line. So if there is another date that needed to be change within the same line it ignores it. I've attempted using global substitution but to no avail. If anyone could give me an idea I would very much appreciate it.

```
use strict;
use Time::Piece ();

my $file = $ARGV[0];
open FILE, $file or die;


while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
chomp $line;
my ($date) = $line =~ m/([A-Z][a-z][a-z] [ \d]{2} \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}[AP]M)/; 

            if ($date eq ''){ 
                    print "$line\n";
                    next;
            }
        my $new_dt = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%b %d %Y %H:%M%p')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

        $line =~ s/$date/$new_dt/g;
        print "$line\n";
}

close FILE;
print "\n";
```

EDIT: Added example

Input:

May 15 2007 12:00AM, , 1, 0, Feb  2 2003 12:00PM

Output:

2007-05-15 00:00:00, , 1, 0, Feb  2 2003 12:00PM

Comment: Could you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: Iterate over the matches found with `m//g`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are replacing all the datetimes that are identical to the first datetime of the line. You don't even try to find any other datetimes.

```
while (<>) {
    s{([A-Z][a-z][a-z] [ \d]\d \d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}[AP]M)}{
        Time::Piece->strptime($1, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    }eg;

    print;
}
```

As it turns out, the subject you chose for your question was quite appropriate :)

---

Note: I changed `%H` (hour as 0..23) to the more appropriate than `%I` (hour as 1..12).

Comment: Well according to my output of my text file it replaces the datetime of each line individually except it ignores any that is after the first datetime within that line. Going to give your code a shot now! Thanks.

EDIT: Works like a charm thank you good sir!

Comment: Not quite. As I said, "You are replacing **all** the datetimes that are **identical** to the first datetime of the line." If you have `May 15 2007 12:00AM ... May 15 2007 12:00AM`, both will get replaced. Other datetimes aren't replaced because you don't even look for them.

Comment: Ahhh thank you for the clarification! Much appreciated. And thanks a lot I did not know you can use the time::piece module within the substitution syntax.

Comment: When you use use `/e`, the replacement expression is treated as an expression which is evaluated for each mach.